# Multi head Attention calculation

Tags: pytorch, multihead-attention

I create a model with a multi head attention layer,

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
query = torch.randn(2, 4)
key = torch.randn(2, 4)
value = torch.randn(2, 4)
model = nn.MultiheadAttention(4, 1, bias=False)
```

```
model(query, key, value)
```

I attempt at matching the attention output obtained,

```
softmax_output = torch.softmax(((query@model.in_proj_weight[:4])@((key@model.in_proj_weight[4:8]).t()))/2, dim=1)
intermediate_output = softmax_output@(value@model.in_proj_weight[8:12])
final_output = intermediate_output@model.out_proj.weight
```

but the `final_output` does not match the attention output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was able to match the output,

```
q_w = query@model.in_proj_weight[:4].t()
k_w = key@model.in_proj_weight[4:8].t()
v_w = value@model.in_proj_weight[8:12].t()

softmax_output = torch.softmax((q_w@k_w.t())/2, dim=1)

attention = softmax_output@v_w

final_output = attention@model.out_proj.weight.t()
```

was missing the transpose earlier